# sh file NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, linux, sh

When i'm running below code on terminal. All was OK. But, when i run it from an sh file. I got error **NoClassDefFoundError**

```
cd /opt/MyClass
java -classpath ./dist/MyClass.jar MyClass
```

My DIrectory Sturcture

```
 - opt
 - - MyClass
 - - - dist
 - - - - MyClass.jar
 - - - myShFile.sh
```

Comment: Have you checked that the class is inside the `MyClass.jar`? `jar tf MyClass.jar | grep MyClass`

Comment: i type your command. It show this "MyClass.class" . FYI. when i run above on terminal line.. it was all ok.. but when on SH file.. it can't @SubOptimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i solved it.

**FIRST**
I tried to check whether i can really run Java with .sh file
so, i put this

```
java -version
```

**SECOND**
After successful, i tried to change the `-classpath` to `-cp`

`java -cp dist/MyClass.jar MyClass`

**CONCLUSION**

```
java -version
java -cp dist/MyClass.jar MyClass
```

Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

You should use correct path. Or you can use absolute path

Comment: i tried /opt/dist/MyClass/dist/MyClass.jar and it was no hope

Comment: Change your first line to 
cd /opt/dist/MyClass

Comment: Could you drop list of directory ls -lh /opt/dist/ ?